# Check if cell is within range, if so, return word "Marginal" in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, equation

I am attempting to check if the value in column N of an excel spreadsheet is within the range of -10 to 10.  If it is, then return the word "Marginal" in column O, else return the value in N.  I am not sure how to go about doing this.  This is the code that I have so far:

```
Sub SearchFolders()
'UpdatebySUPERtoolsforExcel2016
    Dim xOut As Worksheet
    Dim xWb As Workbook
    Dim xWks As Worksheet
    Dim InterSectRange As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set xWb = ActiveWorkbook
    For Each xWks In xWb.Sheets

        xRow = 1
        With xWks
            .Activate                    'Activating the worksheet
            .Cells(xRow, 12) = "Meas-LO"
            .Cells(xRow, 13) = "Meas-Hi"
            .Cells(xRow, 14) = "Min Value"
            .Cells(xRow, 15) = "Marginal"
            LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
            Range("L2").Formula = "=G2+I2"
            Range("L2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("L2:L" & LastRow)
            Range("M2").Formula = "=I2-F2"
            Range("M2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("M2:M" & LastRow)
            Range("N2").Formula = "=min(L2,I2)"
            'Set InterSectRange = Application.Intersect(rng1, rng2)
            'If
            Range("N2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("N2:N" & LastRow)
         End With
         Application.ScreenUpdating = True 'turn it back on

     Next xWks
End Sub
```

Comment: Why do you have Next xWks? Do you really care about each of the worksheets? Can I restructure your code?

Comment: I have that because I want to carry out the calculations and results on all the sheets in the workbook.  Thanks!

Comment: In your code you send things to lastRow, should this rather be lastCol if you want to append the calculation to the same row.

Comment: btw, unless G2 is negative won't `=min(L2,I2)` (i.e. `=min(G2+I2,I2)`) always be I2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
For Each xWks In xWb.Sheets

    xRow = 1
    With xWks
        '.Activate                    '<< not required, and best avoided
        .Cells(xRow, 12) = "Meas-LO"
        .Cells(xRow, 13) = "Meas-Hi"
        .Cells(xRow, 14) = "Min Value"
        .Cells(xRow, 15) = "Marginal"
        LastRow = .UsedRange.Rows.Count
        .Range("L2").Formula = "=G2+I2"
        .Range("L2").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("L2:L" & LastRow)
        .Range("M2").Formula = "=I2-F2"
        .Range("M2").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("M2:M" & LastRow)
        .Range("N2").Formula = "=min(L2,I2)"
        .Range("N2").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("N2:N" & LastRow)

        .Range("O2").Formula = "=IF(AND(N2>=-10, N2<=10), ""Marginal"", N2)"
        .Range("O2").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("O2:O" & LastRow)

     End With
     Application.ScreenUpdating = True 'turn it back on

 Next xWks
```

Answer (score 2):

1. You are using a With ... End With block but ignoring it for the Range calls.
2. You can put the formulas into all of the cells at once. No need to put the formula into the top cell and fill down.

   ```
   With xWks
       .Cells(xRow, 12).resize(1, 4) = array("Meas-LO", "Meas-Hi", "Min Value", "Marginal")
       LastRow = application.max(.cells(.rows.count, "F").end(xlup).row, _
                                 .cells(.rows.count, "G").end(xlup).row, _
                                 .cells(.rows.count, "I").end(xlup).row, _
                                 .cells(.rows.count, "L").end(xlup).row)
       .Range("L2:L" & LastRow).Formula = "=G2+I2"
       .Range("M2:M" & LastRow").Formula = "=I2-F2"
       .Range("N2:N" & LastRow).Formula = "=min(L2,I2)"
   End With
   ```